# CakePHP memcache items expire too early

Tags: cakephp, memcached

I got very strange behaviour with cackephp engine = memcache. The problem is that the cached items always expire earlier than it has. Setting engine = file fix the problem but this is not what i need.
Any help will be appreciated!

P.S. Im using cakephp 1.2.3.8166 stable.

Comment: You might want to provide some sample code showing how you are going about setting the cache. That might let some people have some insight into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct timezone set in php.ini.

Timezone settings influence CakePHP's timestamp generation, and can cause problems when a php generated time (with possible wrong offset) is compared to current time in mysql.